# How do I display a random image retrieved from an array in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to randomly display images from a local file that have been stored in an array in a Card component which is then rendered in the App, the root of the application.

Here is the Images file containing an array of images in the same directory.

```
const woolyImages = [
  require('images/wooly1'),
  require('images/wooly2'),
  require('images/wooly3'),
  require('images/wooly4'),
  require('images/wooly5'),
];

export default woolyImages;
```

Here is the Card component where I attempt to pick a random image from the array and display it using the Image component via 'source'.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import woolyImages from '../images/Images';

function Card() {
  const randomImage =
    woolyImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * woolyImages.length)];
  console.log(randomImage);

  return (
    <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
      <Image source={randomImage} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardContainer: {
    width: '50%',
    height: '35%',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
});

export default Card;
```

(I inserted the pink background so I could be sure it was rendering in the view. It is.)

Finally, here is the root of the application where I render the card.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Card from './components/Card';
import GenerateWoolyButton from './components/GenerateWoolyButton';

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <Card />
      <GenerateWoolyButton style={styles.button} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I am getting the below error.[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to display a randomly generated picture in the Card component and display it in the root of my application? Thank you.

Comment: This error occurs when you either don't have the image in the images folder or you have set incorrect path. Please check you terminal for this error for more information

Comment: Hi @AnkushRishi. Thanks, I updated the paths and they're correct now. I can tell because my image preview extension is working for the paths, but unfortunately the images still aren't rendering.

Comment: are you still facing the same error?

Comment: @SDushan no, but the images still aren't rendering in the Card component. There are no errors, but nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `width` & `height` styles to Image of your Card Component. Such as,

```
<Image source={randomImage} style={{height: 200, width: 200}} />
```

Hope this will helps you. Feel free for doubts.